# Can you right-align an SVG rectangle?

Tags: svg, raphael

I'm using Raphael to draw rectangles. Whoo-hoo!

Is there a way to right align contents of an SVG file?
Not just text, but shapes as well?

I can do the math and get the computed `x` value, but I'm looking for the lazy-simple solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't. Unlike normal web pages where the window is resized and the content flows into it, when a Raphael paper is resized, there is no sort of flow, so aligning is irrelevant. Instead of setting align=right, you just set the right edge to be the same position you set the width of the paper to be. If you enlarge the paper, you can scale the contents with a single operation. Once you've set the position of the right edge, you've essentially set the align position. You don't need to re-set all edge values when the paper changes size, you just scale everything with one command. Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, Jodes. Thanks for your answer. What do you mean by setting the position of the right edge?

Comment: Sorry I was just thinking of drawing a path, when specifying absolute position of a vertex (within the paper). Otherwise it doesn't really apply, you just set the position and the size for most objects.

Comment: Ah, OK. I know I can compute the `x` so that the right edge falls right where I want it, but I wanted to see if there's a lazy solution. Thank you.